# Conditional Distribution of Random Vectors

Tags: probability, matrices, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, conditional-probability

I have the following question:
$Let X,Y\in \mathbb{R}^n$ be jointly distributed random vectors such that:
$$X\sim N_n(\mu, O), Y|X\sim N_n(X,\Sigma)$$
Find the Joint Distribution:
$$X|Y=y$$

I have found the expectation  $\mathbb{E}[Y] = \mu$ and variance $Var(Y) = \mathbb{E}[\Sigma] + O$ using the law of total expectation and law of total variance but I am unsure how to proceed since I do not know how to calculate $Cov(X,Y)$. Would appreciate any guidance.

Answer (score 1):

> ... but I am unsure how to proceed since I do not know how to calculate Cov(X,Y). Would appreciate any guidance.

Begin with the definition:

$\qquad\mathsf{Cov}(X,Y)~=\mathsf E(XY)-\mathsf E(X)\,\mathsf E(Y)$

*Now* apply the Law of Total Expectation.